# How to make a plot from value counts of two different DataFrames in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, seaborn

I have the following two dataframes. I want to plot a lineplot or scatterplot which shall indicate the value counts of "UserId" and "OwnerUserId" on x and y axes. Note that 'UserId' and 'OwnerUserId' indicate the same user, these are just different notations in different dataframes.

I actually want to find out if there is a relation between the total no. of badges a user has (indicated by value counts of 'UserId' to the total no. of posts he has made (indicated by value counts of 'OwnerUserId'.

I have written a code, but don't know if its right.

**Dataframe 1 (badges)**

```
rowId   UserId  Name    Date                   Class    TagBased
    1   1      Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.660  3   False
    2   3      Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.690  3   False
    3   13     Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.690  3   False
    4   14     Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.690  3   False
    5   22     Teacher  2009-09-30T15:17:50.690  3   False
```

**DataFrame 2 (posts)**

```
OwnerUserId   Post Title                                     CreationDate
1             Is a quotient of a reductive group reductive?  2009-09-28T16:11:38.533
2             Learning about Lie groups                      2009-09-28T17:42:23.207
1             Maths                                          2009-09-28T19:41:13.933
```

**Code**

```
x = badges['UserId'].value_counts()
y = posts['OwnerUserId'].value_counts()
sns.scatterplot(x,y)
```

**Note**
All users of first dataframe may not be present in second dataframe. Is there a way I can plot only for those users common to both dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the **posts users** are included in the **badges users**, you can filter the **badges values** with the **posts index**.

```
y = posts['OwnerUserId'].value_counts()
x = badges['UserId'].value_counts()[y.index]
sns.scatterplot(x,y)
```

Else, filter x and y with the common attributes of the 2 dataframes

```
common = list(set(badges.UserId.unique()).union(set(posts.OwnerUserId.unique()))
```